# For self-adjoint operators, eigenvectors that correspond to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

So I was looking for a proof for the next theorem.

$V$ is inner product space

$T: V\rightarrow V$ self adjoint linear map.

$ \lambda_{1},\lambda_{2} \in \mathbb{F}$ so that $ \lambda_{1} \neq \lambda_{2}$

$ v_{1},v_{2} \in V$ so that   $ 0_{v} \neq v_{1} \neq v_{2} \neq 0_{v}$

$T(v_{1}) = \lambda_{1}v_{1}$

$T(v_{2}) = \lambda_{2}v_{2}$

then $\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle = 0$

I searched for a proof but I did not find it.

Please show me the proof or give me a link to where the proof is.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Consider $\langle T v_1 \mid v_2\rangle$. Move things around a bit exploiting what you have been given.

Comment: More generally, this is true for normal operators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you advance, since $T$ is self-adjoint, then

$$ \langle  T v_1,v_2 \rangle =\langle   v_1,Tv_2 \rangle \implies  \langle  \lambda_1 v_1,v_2 \rangle =\langle   v_1,\lambda_2v_2 \rangle \implies (\lambda_1 - \bar{\lambda_2} )  \langle  v_1,v_2 \rangle =0  $$

$$\implies \langle  v_1,v_2 \rangle =0,$$

since $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$

**Note:** Check the inner product properties we used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248486/prove-non-zero-eigenvalues-of-skew-hermitian-operator-are-pure-imaginary).

Comment: I know this result in the real case but in the complex case, you could have $\lambda_2=\overline{\lambda_1}$. How do you "fix" the proof?

Comment: @xavierm02 Hint: $\langle Tv_1,v_1\rangle = \langle v_1, Tv_1\rangle$.

Comment: @user7530: Yeah right. The eigenvalues are real >_<. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If $T$ is self-adjoint,
$$\langle v_1, Tv_2\rangle = \langle Tv_1, v_2\rangle .$$

What do you get when you simplify each side, and use the properties of inner products?