# Complex hermitian matrix: real eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n} $be a symmetric matrix.

$1)$ Prove that its eigenvalues are real and that any two eigenvector associated with different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

$2)$ Is this true if $A\in \Bbb C ^{n\times n} $ and $A$ is hermitian?

I can solve $1)$

For $2)$ I don't see why the conclusions wouldn't hold: if it's hermitian its eigenvalues must be real and if it's hermitian the it's normal so the eigenvector for different eigenvalues will be orthogonal. However I feel this maybe a trick question. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: This is known as the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem). No trick.

Comment: I think you're absolutely correct. Doesn't look like a trick question to me. (Isn't the point of this question to prove what you stated?)

Comment: @milo : You don't need to write $nxn$; you can write $n\times n$.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: Try to imitate this [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248486/prove-non-zero-eigenvalues-of-skew-hermitian-operator-are-pure-imaginary).