# Eigen values and self adjoin operator

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

[image]

Can someone give me a clue about how to solve the b part ?

All I know is the self adjoint formula
$$\langle ku,u\rangle = \lambda\langle  u,u\rangle$$

Comment: Do you know the definition of a self-adjoint?

Comment: You can follow this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248486/prove-non-zero-eigenvalues-of-skew-hermitian-operator-are-pure-imaginary).

Answer (score 2):

Since $K$ is self-adjoint, we have $\langle Ku,v\rangle=\langle u,Kv\rangle$. If $Ku=\lambda u$ and $u=v\ne0$, then
$$
\lambda \langle u,u\rangle=\langle \lambda u,u\rangle=\langle u,\lambda u\rangle=\overline\lambda\langle u,u\rangle,
$$
where the second identity comes from the fact that $K$ is self-adjoint. Since $\langle u,u\rangle=\|u\|^2\ne0$, we conclude that $\lambda =\overline\lambda$ and so $\lambda$ is real.

Comment: Can you give some more inputs regarding this ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: sorry i dint read from where second identity came, but now its clear. thank you.